# How can I make a vbs file which can press arrow keys?

Tags: vbscript

I'm using a voice command software and its still in its beta but really good
The only thing that I find a big problem is navigation in folders and files

So i thought i'll make a vbs script with gets triggered to my voice.
eg: I say left the vbs file which presses left arrow gets pressed

I just need the code for the keystrokes

Once again, move the highlighted folder by pressing arrow keys it what i'm trying to do

Plz somebody help me make a code for this

Thank you

Comment: I found the answer all I did was write 
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.SendKeys "{LEFT}"

Answer (score 0):

may this will help you to create script

```
    'create shell script object which key stork and move arround the screen
    set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

    Set shell = wscript.CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    shell.Open "C:\export\script"

    WshShell.SpecialFolders("C:\export\script")
    WshShell.specialFolders.item(0)
    WshShell.SendKeys "{LEFT}"
    WScript.Sleep 1000
    WshShell.SendKeys "{LEFT}"
    WScript.Sleep 1000
    WshShell.SendKeys "{RIGHT}"
    WScript.Sleep 1000
    WshShell.SendKeys "{DOWN}"
    WScript.Sleep 1000
    WshShell.SendKeys "{DOWN}"
    WScript.Sleep 1000
    WshShell.SendKeys "{DOWN}"
    WScript.Sleep 1000
    WshShell.SendKeys "{RIGHT}"
    WScript.Sleep 1000
    WshShell.SendKeys "{RIGHT}"
    WScript.Sleep 1000
    WshShell.SendKeys "{RIGHT}"
    WScript.Sleep 1000
    WshShell.SendKeys "{RIGHT}"
    WScript.Sleep 1000
    WshShell.SendKeys "{RIGHT}"
    WScript.Sleep 1000
    WshShell.SendKeys "{LEFT}"
    WScript.Sleep 1000
    WshShell.SendKeys "{UP}"
    WScript.Sleep 1000
```

Comment: The keywords must be in curly brackets to emulate cursor keystrokes (`WshShell.SendKeys "{LEFT}"`).